# What are Application.exe.deploy and Application.exe.manifest for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I publish an application from Visual Studio I generally just select `Build -> Publish Solution`, which results in an exe appearing at:

`\Application\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application.exe`

However, when going through the `Publish` menu, I am asked for a file system location:

[image]

And after "publishing" the application there, I can see these files:

```
Application Files
    Resources
        application.ico.deploy
    Application.application
    Application.exe.deploy
    Application.exe.manifest
```

They always seem to be created when I publish in this way, but I have never found any use for them. Am I missing a trick by just publishing applications as a standalone exe?

Comment: They are required by the glue that makes ClickOnce deployment work.  A "standalone exe" doesn't require any deployment help beyond xcopy, ymmv.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment - do you know if there is a way to get VS to stop creating these files, or are they always created when publishing?

Comment: You could stop clicking Publish.  It isn't clear why you think you have to use it if you don't like ClickOnce.